# SELECT with JOIN -> I want to combine these tables with JOIN

Tags: php, sql-server

I have 4 tables:

```
1) tw_Towar: -> tw_Id, tw_Nazwa,tw_SklepInternet
2) tw_Cena: -> tc_Id, tc_CenaNetto1
3) tw_Stan: -> st_TowId, st_Stan
4) tw_ZdjecieTw: -> zd_IdTowar, zd_Glowne
```

I want to combine these tables with JOIN:

First column is part ID , others are properties of part.

I need to get out(SELECT): `tw_Nazwa, tc_CenaNetto1, st_Stan, zd_Glowne`

Thanks

Comment: [MySQL JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

Comment: Do it yourself, in case of an error come back and let's talk about it, SO is not a market when you ask and we do. It's you do and we help in case of you have an error.

Answer (score 0):

As above, you should try to do it first, then come back with the error/exception you encountered. Do you use any framework? You will want to set JOIN on something:
[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)
[Tutotorial for php join](https://www.phpknowhow.com/mysql/joins/)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.tw_Nazwa, c.st_Stan, d.zd_Glowne , d.zd_Zdjecie, a.tw_Id 
FROM tw__Towar  a
LEFT JOIN tw_Cena  b ON a.tw_Id = b.tc_IdTowar
LEFT JOIN tw_Stan c ON b.tc_IdTowar=c.st_TowId
LEFT JOIN tw_ZdjecieTw  d ON d.zd_IdTowar=c.st_TowId 
WHERE zd_IdTowar = ".$_REQUEST['pid']." ";
```

This is working good ;)